# Align an Image with Text

Tags: css, image, html, alignment

I'm trying to align a image with text on its right. I also wanted the image to align vertically with the text.
But when I start writing text, it goes under the image.
Any ideas as how to solve this??

```
<div style="float: left; vertical-align: middle">
<img alt="" src="/portals/85/Images/AukraMaritime.gif" class="Images" />
</div>
<div style="float: left;">
<a href="http:\\www.aukramaritime.no&quot;" class="LinksMenu LeftMenu HoverLinkH1">Aukra Maritime</a>
<br />
<br />
<span>Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. </span><br />
<br />
<a href="http:\\www.aukramaritime.no" class="LinksMenu LeftMenu HoverLink">www.aukramaritime.no</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do your URLs start with ```http:\\```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float:left` from the second `div`.

Notice how the text will start next to the image, and will then float under. To prevent this, add `overflow:hidden` to the text div, or give it a fixed width and float it to the left.

See http://jsfiddle.net/D7gGp/3/.

To align vertically, enclose both the image and the text in a div, absolute position the image, set top:50% together with a margin-top:-(halfImageHeight)px, and push the text to the right to give space for the image. See http://jsfiddle.net/D7gGp/6/.

Comment: It works for the aligning of thex and image, now I need to figure out to center the image vertically in the div. vertical-align:middle does nothing.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/D7gGp/6/. By margin-top:-10px - enter here half the height of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to float your image to the left:

CSS

```
.Images { float:left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use margin to adjust your text

```
.classname {
          margin-top: 15px;
 }

or

.classname{

            margin : 1px 1px 1px 1px; (please change as per your requirement)
                  /*(BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT, TOP)*/
}
```